# Parse Query return whereEqualTo from a Pointer value

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a Parse class that has a pointer to another class... 
I want to count the objects in Class A that have a certain value that is equal to a field in Class B ...

Eg.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassA");
query.whereEqualTo(ClassB.field, mValToCheck); // ?!??!?
query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
  // etc
```

I'm stumped. Thoughts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare a pointer column directly with String or Integer. But if you create a ParseObject you can!

First you have to create a ParseObject to use as a pointer.

```
ParseObject obj = ParseObject.createWithoutData("classNameThatPointedTo","fieldValue");
```

After that , you can compare two fields.

```
query.whereEqualTo("fieldName", obj);
```